# Refocus a textfield form after an AJAX call

Tags: jquery, focus, blur

Trying to refocus a textfield after an AJAX call, for example checking if the login choosen is already taken

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $("#login").blur(function(){
        //AJAX here to check if login already exist
        alert("login already exist");
        $(this).val("");
        $(this).focus();
    });
});
```

The focus is not going back login, code fail. Any help is appreciated.

ANSWER - based on barmar suggestion - thank you :D

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $("#login").blur(function(){

        alert($(this).val());
        //AJAX here to check if login already exist
        $.ajax({              
            type: "GET",
            url: "EmptyServlet",                        
            success: function(){    
                $("#login").val("");
                $("#login").focus();    
            }     
        }); 
    });
});
```

Comment: Everything to be done after an AJAX call should be in the callback function, not the caller.

Comment: you means in the sucsess()?

Comment: Yes, that's what I mean (although jQuery has other ways to declare the callback function).

Comment: FYI, I found the original question a bit unclear, since the way you wrote it, the alert would also appear before the AJAX check returned.

Comment: I just want to simplify it hehe, I edit my question with an answer based on your suggestion